# Nested for loops with initialization outside the loop

Tags: c, nested-loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1, j = 1;

    for(i; i<=5; i++)
    {
        for(j; j<=5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d - %d\n",i, j);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs the outer for loop only once.
The output being :

```
1 - 1
1 - 2
1 - 3
1 - 4
1 - 5
```

But when I make the following change, the printfs get printed the expected 25 times.

```
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d - %d\n",i, j);
        }
    }
```

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple in the second iteration of `i`(when `i=2`) the value of `j` is 6 so the second (the nested one) `for` never runs. But in the second case at each iteration of `i` , `j` is initialized to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

The i loop was running 5 times as expected, but your j loop only ran for the first iteration.
In your first example the j var was incremented up to 6, then never run again (because 6 =/= <=5).

When you changed the j loop to (j=1; ...) it now runs 5 times each time the i loop runs, which is why you get 25 output lines.